# BeautifulSoup search within results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape Yahoo finance for annual performance of mutual funds.  Their page is set up so the data I want is on a line with the same class as many other lines.  There are no unique identifiers. I can index to the line I want but using different stock tickers results in the page changing which also changes the index I would need to use so that won't work.

I'm thinking I could search the page for some unique text, in this case "2010" then grab the "data-reactid="205"" number next to the "2010" value I found and then I could increment the "data-reactid" number to find the line of code I want.  Hopefully this makes sense.

This is my test code so far:

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/APGAX/performance?p=APGAX')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text, features="html.parser")
ree = soup.find_all('span',attrs={"class": "W(10%) D(b) Fl(start) Ta(s)"})
print(ree)
```

Running that code results in about 30 different lines from the page (I tried to paste them here but this website changes the lines I paste so I can't show you that.

The "2010" I want to search for is about 1/3rd of the way down the list and the "data-reactid="205"" number from that same line. The problem is I don't know how to search within the results to find the particular line I want.

Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?  Thanks for the help.  Sorry my description is not good.  I'm pretty new at this but trying to learn Python.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the web page, I recommend you use the Yahoo Finance API. There are [Python libraries for accessing the API](https://algotrading101.com/learn/yahoo-finance-api-guide/).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation.  I looked over the Yahoo Finance API and it looks very good but I don't see the ability to get yearly performance on mutual funds and ETFs. I'm not trying to to do algo trading( at this point) so the daily price data doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for, but please describe the problem clearly.

Instead of binding the url object with "text" bind it with "content"

```
url = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/APGAX/performance?p=APGAX')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.content, features="html.parser")
```

to search within particular line, its good idea to first inspect the html tags to know which tag has the content you want including the correct class name or id name. For example, , the code will look like this..

```
results = soup.find_all('span', class_='W(10%) D(b) Fl(start) Ta(s)')
print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and I'm sorry I wasn't clear about what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to scrape the annual returns from 2010 to 2020 for multiple Mutual Funds and ETFs and put them in an Excel Spreadsheet.  The problem is that many fields on the Yahoo Finance webpage have the same tag and class name.  I can use an index to pick the one that I want but the web page changes depending on if it's a fund or ETF and therefore the index also changes.

Comment: I thought if I could search within that subset of tags for something unique in that particular table (in this case the year 2010), then I could use the "data-reactid="205" that appears in that same line and increment it and then search again using that "data-reactid="209" to collect the annual performance for that year which in this case is 9.41%.  I hope this is clearer than last nights poor attempt to explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I did a little looking around to try to understand binding with .content rather than .text and If I understand, binding with content is with bytes for non text objects. I'm not sure how that helps me in this circumstance.